# Query Post interferes with Pagination

Tags: query, pagination, query-posts

Here is my situation, if you look at the following page: 
http://staging.cancerwellness.com/mind-body/cancerversary/, you will see that the pagination is not working. After researching the problem, I found the problem within the following code:

```
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
       $cat_id = $cat->term_id;

       if($cat->name != 'Uncategorized' && $cat->name != 'Hero') :
          $catURL = get_category_link($cat_id);
          echo "<div class='side-cat'><button>".$cat->name."</button><ul>";
          query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=5");
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
             <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
              <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
             <li><a href="<?php echo $catURL; ?>" title="Read All <?php echo $cat->name; ?> Stories">More. . .</a></li>
                    </ul></div>
               <?php endif;  } ?>
```

The main culprit was the query_posts. Is there an alternative to the query posts so it doesn't interfere with the pagination?

I'm using Wordpress 5.1

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: Query_posts is specifically designed to alter the **main** page query. For additional queries, you can create addition WP_Query objects and operate on them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) is going to alter the main query, and it doesn't sound like you want that. I would recommended using the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) object to get the other posts.

That said, if you must use `query_posts()`, call [`wp_reset_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) at the end of your `foreach` to reset your main query back to the original one.

Comment: Before I read this message, I used the wp_reset_query(); as well and I was going to answer the question.